# Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start is the message in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Whenever I try to start the server in eclipse, the above message crops up.   The following is the error message in the console

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/digester/Rule
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:465)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Tomcat jars were corrupted.

Backup the Webapps folder inside Tomcat Folder.

Remove/Un-install Tomcat.

Re-install the Tomcat and Copy paste Webapps folder and restart server in Eclipse IDE.

If you don't want already deployed apps in Tomcat, re-install the tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

In your project explorer in eclipse, look for Servers folder. Delete it and uninstall the Tomcat server as well. Install the Tomcat server again and configure your web app during the installation.